# How to internationalization errors returned by API?

Tags: api, internationalization

I'm wondering how to manage error in an API with multiple language.

I know there are multiple way to do that. I found 3.

1. Send a statusCode to front (with optionnal some data to manage dynamics values like : "you can manage only **X** users")
2. Send errors for all language ex :

   ```
   {
      en:"error is....",
      fr:"l'erreur est...",
      ...
   }
   ```
3. send just one error in the correct language

   ```
   {
      en:"error is...."
   }
   ```

All of this have pro and cons...

the first :

```
+ API just manage statusCode and front(s) can manage error how it want
- API must manage dynamics error and send extra data
- Front must reformat the error (error + extra data)
others ?
```

the second :

```
+ error message can just be displayed on front without update it (but need to get the good one for the language client)
- back must manage error message for all language (if there are 10-50 or more language it's a little bit annoying)
- back end must take care of displaying message interstanding for a user (I think it's not is role)
others ?
```

the third :

```
+ error message can just be displayed on front without update it
- back end must take care of displaying message interstanding for a user (I think it's not is role)
- front must send the user's language at the session's begining and update this information if user change it
others ?
```

I think the third is the better but I don't know. 
someone could say me what is the best solution and why ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The first option is not viable in many cases because the client needs to know all the error codes beforehand. If you don't mind bandwidth usage second option is not bad. I think the third option is a perfect fit.